# LWJGL OpenGL application limited at ~35 fps

Tags: opengl, netbeans, shader, lwjgl

I ported a volume renderer from c++ using glm and glut to LWJGL, java. The volume renderer uses a shader with a 3d texture. 
For some reason though the fps sticks at ~35 fps. I tried trimming the shader, but it doesn't have any affect on the fps.

Profiler output:
[image]

Java class:
http://pastebin.com/K61mcWzL

Could it be that the limiting factor are the calls to the 3D volume which is probably stored in global memory because of the significant size? This would be odd, because I decreased the number of calls to the volume significantly and that should then result in a higher fps, which it doesn't.

Edit: Also, the Netbeans profiler doesn't give the time per frame, but instead displays the summed time. It does give the number of samples, but dividing the Time by Samples gives me about 10 fps according to my calculations (i.e. display() has 16 samples below). How do I get the accurate time per frame of the Netbeans profiler? (Relevant to this question)

Comment: Is your vsync disabled?

Comment: Yep, vsync is (manually) disabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue was that the uniform locations were fetched every frame, which is much slower than fetching them at start and only fetching them again when they change.

It runs at 120 fps now :)